# Q: Problem - FullSimplify returns 0, FindRoot returns value & FindInstance requires system abend

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, numerics

The function at issue:

```
fa[a_] = 99999.99999999999` (-426.3417145941241` + 2.25` a - 
      2.25` a Erf[
        99999.99999999999` (0.4299932790728411` - 
           0.18257418583505533` Log[a])] + 
      23.714825526419478` Erf[
        99999.99999999999` (0.42999327934670234` - 
           0.18257418583505533` Log[a])]) + 
   9.999999999999998`*^9 a^3.1402269146507883`*^9 E^(
    9.999999999999998`*^9 (-0.36978844033114555` - 
       0.06666666666666667` Log[a]^2)) (a E^(
       1.8749999999999996`*^10 (0.3140226915650789` - 
          0.13333333333333333` Log[a])^2) (0.24259772920294995` - 
         0.10300645387285048` Log[a]) +
      E^(1.8749999999999996`*^10 (-0.3140226913650789` + 
          0.13333333333333333` Log[a])^2) (-2.556961252217486` + 
         1.085680036306589` Log[a]));
```

Build and plot the function - show it is not always zero **and** there is one root.

```
dataa = {#, fa[#]} & /@ Range[1, 1000, 10];
imagea = Plot[fa[a], {a, 0, 400}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.005], Point[dataa]}];
imagea
```

[image: Illustration of non zero function]

`FindRoot` is able to find the root - only if searching from above:

```
FindRoot[fa[a] == 0, {a, 10^10}]
```

> {a -> 100.013}

Show that `FullSimplify` returns zero - with no warning:

```
Assuming[a > 0, FullSimplify[fa[a]]]
```

> 0.

**The following consumes all memory, then thrashes the swap space. 
The only way to interrupt was:
 `alt`+`ctl`+`sysrq`+`REISUB`.**

```
FindInstance[fa[a] == 0 && a > 0, {a}, Reals]
```

Does anyone observe the same behavior?
Is this expected or should be reported as a bug?

System Information:

```
SystemInformationData[{"Kernel" -> {
    "Version" -> "11.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)", 
    "ReleaseID" -> "11.3.0.0 (5944640, 2018030701)", 
    "PatchLevel" -> "0", 
    "MachineType" -> "PC", 
    "OperatingSystem" -> "Unix", 
    "ProcessorType" -> "x86-64", 
    "Language" -> "English", 
    "CharacterEncoding" -> "UTF-8", 
    "SystemCharacterEncoding" -> "UTF-8"

...

  "Machine" -> {"MemoryAvailable" -> 
     Quantity[11.852828979492188, "Gibibytes"], 
    "PhysicalUsed" -> Quantity[5.171413421630859, "Gibibytes"], 
    "PhysicalFree" -> Quantity[10.363525390625, "Gibibytes"], 
    "PhysicalTotal" -> Quantity[15.53493881225586, "Gibibytes"], 
    "VirtualUsed" -> Quantity[5.171413421630859, "Gibibytes"], 
    "VirtualFree" -> Quantity[14.234615325927734, "Gibibytes"], 
    "VirtualTotal" -> Quantity[19.406028747558594, "Gibibytes"], 
    "PageSize" -> Quantity[4., "Kibibytes"], 
    "PageUsed" -> Quantity[3.8710899353027344, "Gibibytes"], 
    "PageFree" -> Quantity[0, "Bytes"], 
    "PageTotal" -> Quantity[3.8710899353027344, "Gibibytes"], 
    "Active" -> Quantity[3.342662811279297, "Gibibytes"], 
    "Inactive" -> Quantity[1.4980888366699219, "Gibibytes"], 
    "Cached" -> Quantity[1.8926506042480469, "Gibibytes"], 
    "Buffers" -> Quantity[225.7890625, "Mebibytes"], 
    "SwapReclaimable" -> Quantity[96.015625, "Mebibytes"]}}]
```

Comment: What is the definition of `fa`?

Comment: Fixed function name.

Comment: Adding the WorkingPrecision->20 option, I immediately obtain "General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation."

Comment: @user64494 which function are you referring to?  Do this mean that, otherwise, you observe the same behavior?  Particularly interested if `FindInstance` cripples your system.

Comment: FindInstance[fa[a] == 0 , {a}, Reals, WorkingPrecision->20]. Hope I am (and was) clear.

Comment: Thanks.  Just to be clear: This means find that `FullSimplify` returns `0.` without any warning or error?  Is this for the same MM version I report (11.3)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your "This means find that FullSimplify returns 0. without any warning or error?". Can you kindly ask your request in other words?. The command FindInstance[fa[a] == 0 , {a}, Reals, WorkingPrecision->20]. reports overflow, not crashing my comp.I use version 12.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: Above the `FindInstance` there is this command `Assuming[a > 0, FullSimplify[fa[a]]]`.  Which returns zero. I'm referring to that command. I also cite this in the subject line.

Comment: Note `Simplify[fa[a]]` is simpler example that returns zero.

Comment: `FindRoot` works for lower values of the starting point for me, greater than around 10.7 below which the derivative suffers from underflow. `FindRoot[fa[a] == 0, {a, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]` fixes that.  I take it the main question is why does `Simplify` return an unreliable answer?

Comment: The issue with `FullSimplify` is almost certainly due to underflow-to-zero. It remains as a known problem without a clear solution. One path would be to force all approximate numbers inside polynomial algebra functions to be bignums (that is, `$MachinePrecision` instead of `MachinePrecision`, for those familiar with the distinction). This seems draconian but might be the best tack for us to take.

Comment: @michael-e2: 

> "I take it the main question is why does Simplify return an unreliable answer?"

Correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that `fa[a]` behaves relatively well with respect to `FindRoot` and plotting but not simplification.  That a computation, whether or not it is `FindInstance[]`, might exhaust system resources is unremarkable, but it's likely that an exact-symbolic computation with floating-point numbers will be worse. On things that would cancel or equal each other, round-off error sometimes makes them not do so, thereby making the problem more complicated.  Also, *Mathematica* might rationalize the numbers and convert them to ratios of very large integers; while that cures the round-off problem, it can make the algebra seem very complicated.

The reason for the failure of `Simplify[fa[a]]` is the behavior of [machine underflow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170416/new-generalmunfl-error-and-loss-of-precision).  Somehow, `Simplify` suppresses the message; probably someone on the site can say how to get the message to be unsuppressed.  A vestige of it can be summoned with `$MessagePrePrint`:

```
ClearSystemCache[];
Block[{$MessagePrePrint = (Print[FullForm@#]; #) &},
 Simplify[fa[a]]
 ]
(*
HoldForm[$MessageList]

HoldForm[Times[-224999.99999999997`,
 8.42822696534888596`6.386636439297712*^-1605970792]]

0.
*)
```

We can see that the expression culled results in underflow:

```
Times[-224999.99999999997`, 
 8.42822696534888596`6.386636439297712*^-1605970792]
```

> General::munfl: -225000. 8.42823*10^-1605970792 is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

```
    (*  0.  *)
```

It's one of the pitfalls of using machine-precision in an exact-symbolic way.  Arbitrary-precision is more robust, but it has its limitations, too.

Remark: You might notice the second factor of `Times` is an arbitrary precision number.  This arose from machine-number overflow.  (Underflow used to work in the same way, but Wolfram changed the behavior in V11.3.)

*Update:* I found the command, or at least another one, that leads to the problem, `Factor`.

```
Factor[fa[a]]
```

> General::munfl: -225000. 8.42823*10^-1605970792 is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

```
(*  0.  *)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think that mixing of huge numbers and machine precision is what's making Mathematica go crazy (so this is not a bug, but a lack of feature). In general, running functions best suited for analytic expression transformations like FullSimplify and FindInstance on expressions with floating point numbers is a bad idea except in simple, well-understood cases.

Let's find a good approximation to your function.

`` E^(9.999999999999998*^9 (-0.36978844033114555 - 0.06666666666666667` Log[a]^2)) `` is almost zero to millions of digits of precision when a>11, so let's replace it exactly with 0.

We're left with a much simpler expression:

```
100000. (-426.342 + 2.25 a - 2.25 a Erf[100000. (0.429993 - 0.182574 Log[a])] + 23.7148 Erf[100000. (0.429993 - 0.182574 Log[a])])
```

When a>11, both Erf functions here become almost equal to -1, so the final approximation is

```
fb[a_] = 100000. (-450.057 + 4.5 a)
```

It's easy to check that with machine precision and a>11 the approximation is equivalent to the original, and finding its zero becomes trivial.

Comment: `FindRoot` seems to do a better job finding the root of the original expression, though.  And it's fast and simple.